# Parameter must be an array or object that implements Countable in PHP function

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, count

The below code in my PHP function is throwing a count() error, whereas this code has previously worked for ~2 years. I'm unable to get ahold of the original developer - hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. The error is being thrown on the first line:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  // output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userId = $row['userId'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $listId = findListIdByUserId($userId, $conn);
    
    if ($userId != null) {
      $response = createContact($email, $listId);
      
      if (array_key_exists('id', $response)) {
        $sendinBlueId = $response['id'];
        $sql = "UPDATE contacts SET status='added', sendinBlueId= $sendinBlueId  WHERE id=".$row['id'];
        
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "Record updated successfully";
        } 
        else {
          echo "Error updating record: ".$conn->error;
        }
      } 
      else {
        $error = $response['code'];

        if ($error == "duplicate_parameter") {
          $response = addContactToList($email, $listId);

          var_dump($response['contacts']['success']);

          if (count($response['contacts']['success']) == 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE contacts SET status='added'  WHERE id=".$row['id'];
            
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
              echo "Record updated successfully";
            } 
            else {
              echo "Error updating record: ".$conn->error;
            }
          }
        } 
        else {
          $sql = "UPDATE contacts SET status=$error  WHERE id=".$row['id'];
          
          if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
          }
          else {
            echo "Error updating record: ".$conn->error;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

> [19-Sep-2023 12:01:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an
> array or an object that implements Countable in
> /home/zho018qfnx0i/public_html/addContactsToList.php on line 42

The echo'd error is:

> Error updating record: Unknown column 'invalid_parameter' in 'field
> list'

Comment: Did you try dumping $response['contacts']['success'] ? What is it and does it implements Countable

Comment: What does `$sql` look like, when executed?

Comment: Dumping $response['contacts']['success'] produces NULL NULL

Comment: I believe the echo'd error I added in my original post is what $sql is producing. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: The echo'd error isn't coming from the code you provided, unless `$row['id']` contains `invalid_parameter`

Comment: Oh, you are correct, I have updated the post with the full code. It looks like it's bombing on the original SQL connection? edit: the PHP count() error is from the if(count($response) statement.. how is it even getting to that point, if the original if statement before that was true (since it's displaying the echo error from that statement)?

Comment: `since it's displaying the echo error from that statement`...how do you know? There are several "Error updating record" outputs in that code, one of which is in the same block as the `if(count($response...` line. And as we can see [here](https://3v4l.org/l0gNu#v7.4.33), getting that warning doesn't stop the code from entering the `if` block where the test was being made. If you upgrade to a supported version of PHP, you'll see that this scenario is  upgraded to a fatal error, as it's clearly liable to lead to unpredictable behaviour in the code.

Comment: Anyway if items in the $response variable are NULL unexpectedly, than that must be as a result of an issue in the `addContactToList` function, which you haven't shown us (since that's the last thing before that which populates the $response variable). So I suggest you debug that function next. If you're still stuck after that, provide a [mre] of the issue showing (relevant parts of) that function, and the results of your additional investigation.

Comment: P.S. As per anyber, I can't see how that "invalid parameter" error could be coming from any of the SQL code shown here, it doesn't make any sense. Unless, as mentioned, `$row['id']` somehow contains the word "invalid_parameter". You really should get the code to log the specific SQL statement that the error relates to. P.P.S...it's 2023, not 2003. Use prepared statements and parameterised queries!!! And use mysqli error reporting instead of this overly-verbose manual error handling. (I know you inherited the code...but this style has been obsolete for 20 years).